# Place Order shows an empty alert message in Magento One Page Checkout

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, magento

I have a Magento store that has been converted to a "one deal at a time" type store, and the checkout process is broken. I've been trying to debug this, but have hit a wall, primarily due to my limited understanding of Magento.

On the saveOrder step, when clicking "Place Order", the page shows "submitting order information, then the message clears and the shopper is still on the Order Review page.

I've analyzed with Firebug, and I can see the order information is being sent

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined method ReflectionMethod::setAccessible() in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/domain/app/code/community/EcomDev/CheckItOut/Model/Type/Onepage.php** on line **348**

submitComplete: function (response) {

```
    this.hideMask();
    try{
        var result = response.responseText.evalJSON();
    }
    catch (e) {
        var result = {};
    }
    if (result.redirect) {
        location.href = result.redirect; 
        return;
    }
    if (result.success) {
        window.location=this.config.success;
    }
    else{
        var msg = result.error_messages;
        if (typeof(msg)=='object') {
            msg = msg.join("\n");
        }
        alert(transport.responseText);
        alert(msg);
    }
}
```

});

I am getting the JS alert with no text, so it looks like transport.reponseText is empty. The main references to empty response text I've found appear to be related to same-origin policy, which I don't think applies, because my AJAX post is to and from www.domainname.com.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method ReflectionMethod::setAccessible() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/domain/app/code/community/EcomDev/CheckItOut/Model/Type/Onepage.php on line 348. I think this *could* be a problem.

Comment: Can you post the 348th line?